# jQuery .trigger('click') not working

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, tampermonkey

This snippet works fine with TamperMonkey, but when I try to use it in a Chrome extension, it doesn't do anything, am I doing something wrong?

It's suppose to like every post of mine on a XenForo forum.

```
$('li[data-author="TesoMayn"]').each(function() {
    $("a.LikeLink").trigger("click");
});
```

More Info:

manifest.json:

```
{
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": [
        "jquery.min.js",
        "autolike.js",
        "autolike.min.css"
    ]
},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "js": [
            "jquery.min.js",
            "autolike.js"
        ],
        "css": [
            "autolike.min.css"
        ],
        "matches": [
            "http://domain.com/*",
            "https://domain.com/*"
        ],
        "run_at": "document_start"
    }
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "jquery.min.css",
    "autolike.js",
    "autolike.min.css"
],
"description": "Autolike My Post",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Autolike",
"permissions": [
    "http://domain.com/",
    "https://domain.com/",
    "cookies",
    "alarms",
    "notifications"
],
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"version": "1.7.5"
}
```

autolike.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var css = chrome.extension.getURL('autolike.min.css');
  $("head").append('<link href="'+ css +'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
  $('li[data-author="TesoMayn"]').each(function() {
      $('a.LikeLink').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

Comment: How do you use it in a Chrome extension? Can you provide more code?

Answer (score 2):

Try [createEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent) instead of trigger().  This simulates a click exactly as if you clicked with your mouse.

```
$('li[data-author="TesoMayn"] a.LikeLink').each(function() {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 80, 20, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
});
```

Comment: Thank you saved me!
jQuery triggers didn't work for me. but this way worked for me